# Apply inputMask but hide it in input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-inputmask

I am using this plugin [InputMask](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask) as mask for my input

```
<input type="text" data-bind="inputMask: { value: hourValue, mask: 'h:s t\\m', jitMasking: true, showMaskOnFocus: false, showMaskOnHover: false, hourFormat: '12', alias: 'datetime'}">
```

I want to apply this mask to input, but never show it to user. I've added all posible properties that I've found, but still it isn't enough to hide mask at all.

Here is example : https://jsfiddle.net/sg7uvhdz/1/ 
Problem - when I remove last item in input, I can see first symbol of mask.

Can I hide it for every case?

Thanks.

```js
$(function() {
  $("input").inputmask();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.date.extensions.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" data-inputmask="'mask': 'h:s t\\m', 'jitMasking': true, 'showMaskOnFocus': false, 'showMaskOnHover': false, 'hourFormat': '12', 'alias': 'datetime'">
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are asking. You want to have a mask on there but not show it. Masks are usually applied for 2 reasons; to make the user interaction easier, and to apply inherit validation on the data. Are you trying to just use this to make sure format of the input is correct?

Comment: I am confused as to why you want to apply a mask to something the user cant see.

Comment: @Keith.Abramo, yes, you are right, I do this to ensure format of date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve the desired using the oncleared method.

```
$(function(){

    $("input").inputmask({oncleared: function() {

     $("input").val("");

  }});
})
```

```js
$(function(){

   $("input").inputmask({oncleared: function() {
  
     $("input").val("");
  
  }});
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/jquery.inputmask.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.inputmask/3.3.3/inputmask/inputmask.date.extensions.min.js"></script>


<input type="text" data-inputmask="'mask': 'h:s t\\m', 'jitMasking': true, 'showMaskOnFocus': false, 'showMaskOnHover': false, 'hourFormat': '12', 'alias': 'datetime'">
```

fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/c19f8vfm/

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to not apply a mask on that input and then attach an event listener on blur which checks if the input is valid by calling `isValid`

Something like

```
var isValid = Inputmask.isValid("<input value>", { alias: "h:s t\\m"});
```